# jQuery id is undefined in one block but not the other?

Tags: jquery

Forgive the big block of code but I am stuck and getting really burned out on this...

So I am loading some content and then displaying a Dialog. Depending upon which button you press I do several things. My inconsistancies seem to be between the Save Schedule and Cancel Send blocks

This code is the same in both blocks

```
var dt = $(this).find("input[type=text]").val();
var id = $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("id");
var CustomObjectKey = id.split("_")[1];
var alt = $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("alt");
```

However in the Cancel send block the id is undefined and therefore the split is blowing up.

Can anyone tell mw what I am doing wrong please?

```
$("#ActionContainer").load(wsUrl, { Function:"BuildScheduleDialog", ArticleID:ArticleID}, function(){
                var Subject = $(this).find("#hdnSubject").val();
                $("#ActionContainer").dialog({
                    title: "Edit Schedule: " + ArticleTitle,
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: 'auto',
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Cancel': function() {

                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        },
                        'Save Schedule': function() {
                            var that = $(this);
                            var table = $("#tblSchedule");
                            var parameterArray = [];

                            //loop each row of the Schedule table to get the parameters
                            $(table).find("tbody>tr").not(':first').each(function () {
                                var dt = $(this).find("input[type=text]").val();
                                var id = $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("id");
                                var CustomObjectKey = id.split("_")[1];
                                var alt = $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("alt");

                                //alert(dt + " " + id + " " + CustomObjectKey + " " + alt);
                                if(dt != "" && alt === "")
                                {
                                    parameterArray.push({Region: $(this).find("#spRegion").text(), Date: dt, ArticleTitle: ArticleTitle ,ArticleID: ArticleID, PublicationTypeID: PublicationTypeID, CustomObjectKey: CustomObjectKey, Subject: Subject});
                                }
                            });

                            if(parameterArray.length > 0)
                            {
                                ShowWaitIcon();
                                $("#results").load(wsUrl, { Function:"Schedule", Action: "Edit", Items: JSON.stringify(parameterArray)}, function(){
                                    $("#results").fadeIn(1000);
                                    $('#results').delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
                                    $(that).dialog('close');
                                    LoadMainTable();
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert("Please select at least one Item to Schedule");
                            }

                        },
                         'Cancel Send': function() {
                         if(confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel this entire send?"))
                         {
                             var that = $(this);
                             var table = $("#tblSchedule");
                             var parameterArray = [];

                             var status = "";
                             $(table).find("tbody>tr").each(function () {                                    
                                var dt = $(this).find("input[type=text]").val();                                     
                                 var id = $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("id");                                     
                                 var CustomObjectKey = id.split("_")[1];                                     
                                 var alt = $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("alt");                                                                         
                                parameterArray.push({Region: $(this).find("span").text(), Date: dt, ArticleTitle: ArticleTitle ,ArticleID: ArticleID, PublicationTypeID: PublicationTypeID, CustomObjectKey:CustomObjectKey});
                             });

                             /*ShowWaitIcon();
                             $("#results").load(wsUrl, { Function:"CancelAllSchedule", Items: JSON.stringify(parameterArray)}, function(){
                                $("#results").fadeIn(1000);
                                $('#results').delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
                                $(that).dialog('close');
                                LoadMainTable();
                             });

                         */}
                        }
                    },open: function(event, ui){
                        $(".datePicker", "#ActionContainer").datetimepicker({
                            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
                            showTimezone: true
                        });
                        BindCheckboxes();
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Better to write a function once than copy and paste code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `$(table).find` below with just `table.find` (since you've already declared `table = $("#tblSchedule")`

```
                         var table = $("#tblSchedule");
                         var parameterArray = [];

                         var status = "";
                         $(table).find("tbody>tr").each(function () {                                    
                            var dt = $(this).find("input[type=text]").val();                                     
                             var id = $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("id");                                     
                             var CustomObjectKey = id.split("_")[1];                                     
                             var alt = $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("alt");                                                                         
                            parameterArray.push({Region: $(this).find("span").text(), Date: dt, ArticleTitle: ArticleTitle ,ArticleID: ArticleID, PublicationTypeID: PublicationTypeID, CustomObjectKey:CustomObjectKey});
                         });
```

Also, if you're trying to select each `tr` from `$("#tblSchedule")`, `$("#tblSchedule").find("tr")` may be a better selector.